# How to install USB modem for wireless Internet on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb, internet, modem

I need to install the MF195E USB modem supplied by the European ISP "Orange" on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Currently the system does not seem to respond at all when inserting the USB modem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the usual methods? Go to network manager, add a new mobile broadband connection, choose your country, isp and billing plan. After the whole thing's done you should be good to go.

Comment: when you try to add a new boardband connection, you have to choose a device. the problem here, the device is not shown.